# How to redirect from server, without the #url from the client?

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, sails.js, marionette, passport.js

I have a node.js (sail.js) project as server side, with backbone.marionette as client.

I'm using passport to determine if the user is authenticated.

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next)
{
  if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();
  else  
    res.redirect('/login');
}
```

My problem is:

if the current url is: `http://localhost:1337/#users` (with #users from client), and the server session is timeout, the `res.redirect('/login');` redirects the page with the client url, like this: `http://localhost:1337/login#users`

Is there a way to redirect without the #url ?

Comment: You can only remove the location hash on the clientside, so redirect to a route that does `window.location.hash = ''` and then redirects to `/login`

Comment: This code is server code. `window is not defined`

Comment: I realize that, that's why I suggested linking to a route that has *clientside* code that removes the hash, and then redirects to `/login`

Comment: You're not getting it, the hash is not available on the serverside, you have to output a script tag containing `window.location.hash = ''` and you could do that by linking to a route that outputs such a script tag, removes the hash **on the clientside** and then redirects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solusion:

We can workaround this problem by redirecting to `/login#`. This should do the trick and remove the hash from the URL.

Answer (score 0):

the # part is not send to the server, # is added by marionette. marionette received 302 status and redirect to login and smartly trying to resume the #users state. so in this case you don't do redirect in server just do res.render("login").

Comment: I know the `#` part is not sent to the server. But I can't remove it. When refreshing the page/open new tab, I have no where to get the status and redirect to login in the client. So I can only redirect in the server.